# Order by attribute and randomize recurrent

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Given that Venue has a field "featured_level" that could go from 0 to N.

I need to return venues ordered by featured_level, **but randomizing the order of the venues with the same featured_level**.

UPDATE:

Using the given answer I have this method:

```
def self.by_featured_level
  all.group_by {|v| v.featured_level}.inject([]) { |memo, (level,values)|
    memo << { level => values.shuffle }
  }.map { |hash| hash.values }.flatten.reverse
end
```

But it fails the following test (also doesn't work properly with real numbers), I'm still trying to figure it out, test used:

```
describe "by featured level" do
  before do

    @venue1 = create(:venue, featured_level: 5)
    @venue2 = create(:venue, featured_level: 2)
    @venue3 = create(:venue, featured_level: 4)
    @venue4 = create(:venue, featured_level: 2)
    @venue5 = create(:venue, featured_level: 0)
    @venue6 = create(:venue, featured_level: 2)
    @venues = Venue.by_featured_level

  end

  it { 
    start_with_hightest = @venues.index(@venue1) == 0
    expect(start_with_hightest).to be_truthy
  }
  it {
    second_hightest_is_2nd = @venues.index(@venue3) == 1
    expect(second_hightest_is_2nd).to be_truthy
  }
  it {
    ends_with_lowest = @venues.last.id == @venue5.id
    expect(ends_with_lowest).to be_truthy
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally needed an ActiveRecord::Relation instead of an Array (which is return by @zezetic's answer, so in the end I did:

```
scope :by_featured_level, -> {
      select("venues.*, (random() * 9 + 1) AS rdn").order('featured_level DESC, rdn') }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by collecting the venues:

```
require 'ostruct'

@venue1 = OpenStruct.new(id: :a, level: 0)
@venue2 = OpenStruct.new(id: :b, level: 2)
@venue3 = OpenStruct.new(id: :c, level: 2)
@venue4 = OpenStruct.new(id: :d, level: 2)
@venue5 = OpenStruct.new(id: :e, level: 4)
@venue6 = OpenStruct.new(id: :f, level: 5)

@venues = [@venue1, @venue2, @venue3, @venue4, @venue5, @venue6]
```

We want to randomize per level, so we'll create groups:

```
@venues.group_by { |v| v.level }
```

This returns a hash where the venues are indexed by each level.

Now to iterate over the hash and return a new hash where the values have been randomized:

```
@venues.
  group_by {|v| v.level}.
  inject([]) { |memo, (level,values)|
   memo << { level => values.shuffle }
  }
```

This hash can now be flattened so the final result is a list of hashes, randomized per level:

```
@venues.
  group_by {|v| v.level}.
  inject([]) { |memo, (level,values)|
   memo << { level => values.shuffle }
  }.
  map { |hash| hash.values }.
  flatten
```

Comment: I get this error:
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Full test:
http://pastebin.com/XgW3RnjM

Comment: Still doesn't work properly, I updated the code with the implementation and test.